# Mutex Constructor in .NET is strange?

Tags: .net, constructor, mutex

I was looking at the [Mutex(Boolean, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf.aspx) page and i'm completely confused. If i pass true how do i check if the mutex is owned by me or now? Then i saw [Mutex(Boolean, String, out Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k.aspx) and can use the 3rd param to check.

I'm extremely confused. I tested, new mutex doesnt return null or throw an exception if another process is holding the named mutex. But with the other i can  check via paran. So whats the point of that constructor and [Mutex(Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ce4b328.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a *named* mutex, but don't want to own it, it seems like the ideal overload to use:

> If `name` is not null and `initiallyOwned` is **true**, the calling thread owns the mutex only if the named system mutex was created as a result of this call. *Since there is no mechanism for determining whether the named system mutex was created*, it is better to specify **false** for `initiallyOwned` when calling this constructor overload.

(*Emphasis added*)

If you use the `Mutex(Boolean)` constructor creates a *local* mutex - one not visible outside of your program.

---

It appears that the designers of this class favored consistent parameter ordering in the constructor overloads - some might have designed this particular constructor without the `initiallyOwned` parameter at all - just with the `name`. But that's more of a stylistic choice.

Comment: I think its the 'consistent parameter ordering' reason. Although i cant ever see why `Mutex(bool)` would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

The `Mutex(Boolean, String, out Boolean)` surely always will return not null since it is a constructor as well as the other two. Constructors never return null.

The `Mutex(Boolean, String)` is used for almost the same reason with the exception in a case if you do not want to know if it was created by you.

The `Mutex(Boolean)` I believe serves the same thing with the exception, that is, the mutex is created unnamed and is shared only inside one (yours) process.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is on the page to link to under remarks

`If name is not null and initiallyOwned is true, the calling thread owns the mutex only if the named system mutex was created as a result of this call. Since there is no mechanism for determining whether the named system mutex was created, it is better to specify false for initiallyOwned when calling this constructor overload. You can use the Mutex(Boolean, String, Boolean) constructor if you need to determine initial ownership`

The 2 args constructor should only be used if you aren't concern with whether or not you are actually successful in acquiring ownership.

I grant you that it's odd to have an argument and recommend only ever passing one value for said argument